# Spring Security CORS Blocked By Policy

Tags: spring, spring-security

This should be easy, but of course since it's Spring Security, it's not.

I am attempting to access a relatively simple api running as a Spring Boot application from an Angular application. Angular makes the calls to the API just fine, but the backend blocks the request due to CORS policy:

I added the following to my Security configuration:

```java
    @Bean
    public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("https://localtest.me:4200","http://localtest.me:4200"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET","POST"));
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }

    @Bean
    @Profile("dev")
    public SecurityFilterChain devFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        
        // define a custom filter, irrelevant to question
        
        // @formatter:off
        http
            .addFilterAfter(filter, ConcurrentSessionFilter.class)
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/path1","/path2","/logout").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .cors();

        // @formatter:on
        return http.build();
        
    }
```

This STILL does not prevent the CORS policy block.

I've also tried putting various iterations of `@CrossOrigin` (with and without `origins` argument):

- on the Controller class
- on the endpoint method itself

Am I making a simple error causing this?

Edit: I added breakpoints to Spring's CorsFilter, and they are not being hit.

Edit: Adding screenshot by request:

[image]

[image]

Comment: You didn't send a `origin` header in your request. What browser do you use?

Comment: Chrome. It didn't work with Firefox either. The request to api/ is being made by an Angular application.

Comment: Yes, Spring Boot showed it was running on dev profile. Removing the profile annotations entirely did not help.

Comment: There was no response code.

Comment: Can you access the endpoint with Postman?  What response code do you get with Postman?

Answer (score 1):

try to add this at the head ( beggining of your controller)

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:{youy_angular_application_port}")
public class YourRestController {
}
```

Comment: are u setting this Access-Control-Allow-Origin from angular request side ( when calling the api ) ?    from spring side try also @CrossOrigin(origins = "*")

Comment: The ```@CrossOrigins(origins="*")``` didn't help. It doesn't look like the request from the Angular app does not seem to contain any of the allow-* headers, but Chrome makes sure to tell me that I'm only looking at provisional headers. Looking at various docs about configuring Angular for CORS, they all seem to start with "only do this if you can't fix your server".

Answer (score 1):

Not the proudest and most beautiful solution, but some months ago, I also needed to expose some endpoints to my frontend, so my angular application could send requests to them.

```
    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/user").allowedOrigins("http://localhost:4200");
                registry.addMapping("/post").allowedOrigins("http://localhost:4200");
                registry.addMapping("/post/").allowedOrigins("http://localhost:4200");
                registry.addMapping("/user/{id}").allowedOrigins("http://localhost:4200");
                registry.addMapping("/post/{id}").allowedOrigins("http://localhost:4200");
                registry.addMapping("/post/user").allowedOrigins("http://localhost:4200");
                registry.addMapping("/post/user/").allowedOrigins("http://localhost:4200");
                registry.addMapping("/post/user/{id}").allowedOrigins("http://localhost:4200");
                registry.addMapping("/user/").allowedOrigins("http://localhost:4200");
            }
        };
    }
```

The bean can get implemented where ever, since its a bean. In my case I implemented it in the MainApplication.java class.

Comment: Did you do anything in your security config? I just tried this with no luck.

Comment: @Jason No, it was just this piece of code I used in the MainApplication. It could be, that this does not work anymore or is deprecated in the newer versions of spring / spring security. Although not sure here.

Comment: @tstdplt Your solution never worked in combination with Spring Security. Your solution is only for Spring Web endpoints without security.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, here's what happened.

At end-of-day the day before yesterday, some numbskull checked in a change to application.properties changing the context-root of the application.

The application was no longer being served at http://localtest.me:8000/api , it was being servered at http://localtest.me:8000/appname/api.

Effectively, I had a 404 error as much as I had a CORS error. Chrome didn't tell me that the path didn't exist, it just kept telling me it was blocked.